# Run Access Queries via Interop?

Tags: c#, ms-access, com, interop

I have a few MS-Access queries in several `*.mdb` files. They are quite complex.
So I just want to open a file, run specific queries which it contains and get a resulting table back.
**How can I do that ?**

*(I know we can just connect via connection string etc. but I want to explore this way.)*

---

**My sample code (edited to disable security alerts):**

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;

var app = new Application();
app.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"C:\test.mdb", true);
app.AutomationSecurity = MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityLow;
app.Visible = false;
// run query
app.Quit();
```

**Sample query:**

```
select date(), date()-1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run the query from within an instance of the Microsoft Access application (e.g., to run queries that use custom VBA functions and other features that may not be available to queries from direct System.Data.OleDb or System.Data.Odbc connections) you can do something like this:

```csharp
var accApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
accApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Database cdb = accApp.CurrentDb();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Recordset rst = 
        cdb.OpenRecordset(
            "SELECT FullName FROM ClientQuery", 
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenSnapshot);
while (!rst.EOF)
{
    Console.WriteLine(rst.Fields["FullName"].Value);
    rst.MoveNext();
}
rst.Close();
accApp.CloseCurrentDatabase();
accApp.Quit();
```

Comment: @Govert - I had to roll back your edit because it resulted in compile errors: *"The type or namespace name 'Dao' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"*. I have found that `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access` can sometimes produce odd results like that.

Comment: Sorry - I should have checked. It was a moment of hubris.

Comment: Do you know whether the VBA functions in SQL queries work even if one opens the database via `new DBEngine()` and not with the full Access `new Application()`?

Comment: @Govert No, they won't. It's the `Access.Application` object that provides the hook into VBA. A direct DAO connection is unable to "see" the VBA functions, just like a direct OLEDB or ODBC connection.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Can you give me a hint how to open it in background (without any gui) ? A **security warning** is popping up that blocks the process to continue (requires manual input).

Comment: @Bitterblue Perhaps one of the suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/226291/2144390) might help.

Comment: @GordThompson Not really. See my edited code. It didn't hide _everything_ but my process is not blocked anymore.